# Declare assigned property to returned function

Tags: node.js, typescript2.2

I am doing some pretty crazy stuff with this, but it's been working for awhile:

```
function foo(cb){

   return function bar(){

       if(bar.x){
         cb();
       }

   }


}
```

don't ask why :), but it's been working for me. Now I am converting this JavaScript code to TypeScript. Is there a way to declare the type of the returned function so I can declare the function has a property called "x"?

Answer (score 0):

Duh, I always forget this is how you do it!

```
interface IMyReturnedFn {
  (): void,
  x: string,
}


function foo(cb) : IMyReturnedFn {

   return function bar(){

       if(bar.x){
         cb();
       }

   }

}
```

now the returned function has a type! voila